# Have users store and view data - Better than excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I am curious about what other companies are doing as it seems that there must be some solution between Excel and custom apps for having users store large sets of data. I am thinking of data that would generally be uniform and need to have rules and validation applied to it. I wonder too if the answer/solution would be different if there was relational data (e.g. multiple entries per customer). We have in-house employees who are familiar microsoft full stack developers but in some cases it feels that going that route is overkill and that Excel isn't quite robust enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most companies use databases.  Whether or not one uses a SQL or NoSQL type database is determined by your data set.

MariaDB,mysql,MSSQL (Microsoft) are common choices.

Databases support username and password authentication so a user maybe restricted to specific databases,tables, or etc.  Additional users can be limited to only specific right on specific tables.

```
grant <permissions> on database.* (database.table) to username;
```

One can connect to almost any database via ODBC in windows.

Databases are so common almost every programming language has support for accessing databases.

You can use procedure and/or functions built-in to the database to help process the data.  **Triggers** can also be used to pre-screen data before it goes into the table.

Since databases are ubiquitous all ways are used.  Many simply use Microsoft Access either as a database, or to connect to there database and manipulate the records.  MS Access even support GUI forms for end users.  LibreOffice **base** (part of the libreoffice suite) can also be used.

I have used Powerbuilder( I don't know if its still common or not) think visual basic for databases.

I also program in C,php,visual basic scripting, python, and other to connect to a database and manipulate records.

> What interface would you think most people are doing the data input
>   and manipulation with? Custom software or third party?

There is no such thing as "common" people use whatever works.

For example inventory:

1. Have a user manually enter the database into a database via MS Access,libre base or any one of hundreds of choices.
2. Write a script to queries the devices, and automatically populate the database.

In this case #2 is the obvious choice.

However, then an auditor or inventory specialist might view the data in MS access simply because its easier for them. Even if you store your data in a Mariadb,mysql, or MSSSQL database it can still be viewed in a third party application.

Many companies start with a third party solution, but if they are big enough they can afford to develop there own custom interface.

Lots of companies use PHP or similar to make an entirely web based solution so users don't need to have anything installed on there PC.  Obviously, the interface is customized for the specific needs of the company.

Comment: Thank you for that input. What interface would you think most people are doing the data input and manipulation with? Custom software or third party?

Comment: @donL updated answer.